# BeautifulSoup: what's the difference between 'lxml' and 'html.parser' and 'html5lib' parsers?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

**When using Beautiful Soup what is the difference between 'lxml' and  "html.parser" and "html5lib"?**

When would you use one over the other and the benefits of each? When I used each they seemed to be interchangeable, but people here correct me that I should be using a different one. I'd like to strengthen my understanding; I've read a couple posts on here about this but they're not going over the uses much in any at all.

Example:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From the [**docs**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)'s summarized table of advantages and disadvantages:

1. **html.parser** - `BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")`

   - Advantages: Batteries included, Decent speed, Lenient (as of Python 2.7.3 and 3.2.)
   - Disadvantages: Not very lenient (before Python 2.7.3 or 3.2.2)
2. **lxml** - `BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")`

   - Advantages: Very fast, Lenient
   - Disadvantages: External C dependency
3. **html5lib** - `BeautifulSoup(markup, "html5lib")`

   - Advantages: Extremely lenient, Parses pages the same way a web browser does, Creates valid HTML5
   - Disadvantages: Very slow, External Python dependency

Answer (score 18):

The key differences are highlighted in the BeautifulSoup documentation:

- [Differences between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)

The basic reasoning why would you prefer one parser instead of others:

- `html.parser`- built-in - *no extra dependencies needed*
- `html5lib` - *the most lenient* - better use it if HTML is broken
- `lxml` - *the fastest*

Comment: Thanks - `html5lib` (as a parser of broken HTML) just saved my bacon