# Find all end-nodes that contain text using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and BeautifulSoup4

I'm trying to extract (only) the textual content of all tags that are either 'div','p','li' and only from the immediate node, not the child nodes - hence the two options `text=True, recursive=False`

These are my attempts:

```
content = soup.find_all("b", "div", "p", text=True, recursive=False)
```

and

```
tags = ["div", "p", "li"]
content = soup.find_all(tags, text=True, recursive=False)
```

Both of these give me no output, do you know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT - adding more code and a sample doc that I'm testing with, `print(content)` is empty

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list"
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

tags = ["div", "p", "li"]
content = soup.find_all(tags, text=True, recursive=False)

print(content)
```

Comment: What does your HTML document look like?

Comment: I plan to use it on many differnt HTML docs, I've done similar things with JSoup in Java ... but it's a different way of thinking - will add more code now

Comment: You should set `recursive=True`(since there is no immediate node), or use methods such as `find_all_previous/find_all_next`, and it is better to use `lxml` instead of `html.parser`.

Comment: thanks William recursive=False was intentional, but I believe you're saying that without a specific node to traverse recursive=False won't find anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your Question and comments on the previous answer I think you are trying to find

> - the innermost tags
> - that are either 'p' or 'li' or 'div'
> - Should contain some text

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import NavigableString

url = "https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list"
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
def end_node(tag):
    if tag.name not in ["div", "p", "li"]:
        return False
    if isinstance(tag,NavigableString): #if str return
        return False
    if not tag.text: #if no text return false
        return False
    elif len(tag.find_all(text=False)) > 0: #no other tags inside other than text
        return False
    return True #if valid it reaches here
content = soup.find_all(end_node)
print(content) #all end nodes matching our criteria
```

Sample of the output

```
[<p>These instructions illustrate all major features of Beautiful Soup 4,
with examples. I show you what the library is good for, how it works,
how to use it, how to make it do what you want, and what to do when it
violates your expectations.</p>, <p>The examples in this documentation should work the same way in Python
2.7 and Python 3.2.</p>, <p>This documentation has been translated into other languages by
Beautiful Soup users:</p>, <p>Here are some simple ways to navigate that data structure:</p>, <p>One common task is extracting all the URLs found within a page’s &lt;a&gt; tags:</p>, <p>Another common task is extracting all the text from a page:</p>, <p>Does this look like what you need? If so, read on.</p>, <p>If you’re using a recent version of Debian or Ubuntu Linux, you can
install Beautiful Soup with the system package manager:</p>, <p>I use Python 2.7 and Python 3.2 to develop Beautiful Soup, but it
should work with other recent versions.</p>, <p>Beautiful Soup is packaged as Python 2 code. When you install it for
use with Python 3, it’s automatically converted to Python 3 code. If
you don’t install the package, the code won’t be converted. There have
also been reports on Windows machines of the wrong version being
installed.</p>, <p>In both cases, your best bet is to completely remove the Beautiful
Soup installation from your system (including any directory created
when you unzipped the tarball) and try the installation again.</p>, <p>This table summarizes the advantages and disadvantages of each parser library:</p>, <li>Batteries included</li>, <li>Decent speed</li>, 
....
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over your tags, then apply [`soup.find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names) on each tag:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list"
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="lxml")

tags = ["div", "p", "li"]

for tag in tags:
    content = soup.find_all(tag, recursive=True)

    for x in content:
        print(x)
```

Which prints out each `<div>`, `<p>` and `<li>` tag on the HTML page.

You can also set `recursive=True` to traverse the document recursively and extract all nested child tags. If you don't want these nested children, keep `recursive=False`.

You can also use [`lxml`](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/) instead, which is faster than [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html). You can see the differences in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494505/python-difference-between-lxml-and-html-parser-and-html5lib-with-beautifu/45494776#45494776). This might be beneficial if the HTML document is very big.

Comment: `recursive=True` seems to be the default for `find_all`

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes according to @Bitto Bennichan's answer. By checking the next children, this should extract tags containing NavStr within. For example, it would extract `<p>test<b>Strong</b></p>` instead of ignoring it.

```py
def child_contains_navstr(children_tags):
  func = lambda child: isinstance(child.string, NavigableString)
  return map(func, children_tags)

def end_node_with_text(tag, incl_embed_navstr=True):
  if tag.name not in ["div", "p", "li"]:
    return False

  # check if the children nodes have deeper tag or 
  # just NavigableString, <em><b><strong> etc....
  nav_str_res = list(child_contains_navstr(tag.findChildren()))
  if all(nav_str_res) and nav_str_res:
    # print(children)
    return True if incl_embed_navstr else False

  # check if there it is a empty text node
  if not tag.text.replace('\n', ''):
    return False

  # check if there are some other tag wrapping around 
  if len(tag(text=False)) > 0:
    return False
  
  # final node
  return True
```