# Python BeautifulSoup find() not working properly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a program which should go and get the title of the amazon product of the URL:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0756CYWWD?tag=productfinder-headphones-uk-21&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

title = soup.find_all(id="productTitle")

print(title)
```

But when i run it i get `None`. When i tried to switch the id to `priceblock_ourprice` i got again `None`. Also the the `requests` library works perfectly fine. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `html.parser` use `lxml`:

1st: install `lxml` parser by following command `pip install lxml`

then try the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0756CYWWD?tag=productfinder-headphones-uk-21&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
title = soup.find_all(id="productTitle")


print(title[0].get_text(strip=True))


#output Bose QuietComfort 35 (Series II) Wireless Headphones, Noise Cancelling with Alexa built-in  - Black
```

Comment: I get   `bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
`

Comment: yeah you should install `lxml` parser. use `pip install lxml`

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with parsing HTML with `html.parser`, it's not very lenient and pretty minimalistic. But it's not very good at parsing broken HTML (which is very common on the internet, for huge pages). `html5lib` is the slow and feature rich - it parses the page the same way a web browser does.

If you change this line-

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
```

To-

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
```

You'll be able to use `.find_all` as you might expect.

`lxml` will also work for this case, and might actually be a better solution.

For more information, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494505/python-difference-between-lxml-and-html-parser-and-html5lib-with-beautifu) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55880415/beautifulsoup-different-parsers)

The official bs4 docs also explains this specific behaviour, read [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)

Answer (score 1):

Use `lxml` parser

```
In [38]: import requests
    ...: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    ...:
    ...: URL = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0756CYWWD?tag=productfinder-headphones-uk-21&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1"
    ...:
    ...: headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"}
    ...:
    ...: page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    ...:
    ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
    ...:
    ...: title = soup.find_all(id="productTitle")
    ...:
    ...: print(title[0].get_text(strip=True))
Bose QuietComfort 35 (Series II) Wireless Headphones, Noise Cancelling with Alexa built-in  - Black
```