# Converting HTML table to CSV file using python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am very new to pandas, so I wanted to convert this HTML table to CSV file with the pandas however my CSV file is giving me a weird sign and it didn't manage to covert all the table over to the CSV.
Here's my code. I read about using beautifulsoup but I'm not too sure how to use the function.

```
import as pandas
df = pd.read_html('https://aim-sg.caas.gov.sg/aip/2020-10-13/final/2020-09-10-Non-AIR'
              'AC/html/eAIP/ENR-3.1-en-GB.html?s=B2EE1C5E1D2A684224A194E69D18338A560504FC#ENR-3.1')
df[0].to_csv('ENR3.0.csv')
```

Thank you!

Edited: I have changed my import to `import pandas as dp` but i still did not manage to convert all the HTML table to CSV file.

Greatly appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas` itself to do this. You have messed up with the `import` statement. Here is how you do it correctly:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://aim-sg.caas.gov.sg/aip/2020-10-13/final/2020-09-10-Non-AIR'
              'AC/html/eAIP/ENR-3.1-en-GB.html?s=B2EE1C5E1D2A684224A194E69D18338A560504FC#ENR-3.1')

df[0].to_csv('ENR3.0.csv', index = False)
```

If you want to get all the `dataframes` present within the variable `df`, then replace the last line with this:

```
for x in range(len(df)):
    df[x].to_csv(f"CSV_File_{x+1}", index = False)
```

Comment: hi there, I have edited my programming. However, it's still not converting all the HTML table over to CSV file.

Comment: yup, I changed my import statement to "import pandas as pd"

Comment: Ok...Do one thing. Open a new file, just copy paste the code that I have provided, and check if it works.

Comment: I use the code you provided but it is not converting all the table from HTML to CSV.

Comment: Then just use ```df.to_csv``` instead of ```df[0].to_csv```

Comment: an error " AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv' " pop out when i use df.to_csv

Comment: You can do one thing. Just loop through the variable ```df```, and export everything to a csv, like this:  ```for x in range(len(df)):                      df[x].to_csv(f"CSV_File_{x+1}", index = False)```

Comment: I have also updated the same in my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in import statement
It should be `import pandas as pd` and not `import as pandas`, as your are using alias `pd` in the code below.

Study about beautiful soup and use lxml parser to parse required data ( it is very fast ).

This link might help you out: 
[BeautifulSoup different parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55880415/beautifulsoup-different-parsers)

If any other help is required, then do leave a comment on this post and will try to sort our your issue :)

Made correction in your code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://aim-sg.caas.gov.sg/aip/2020-10-13/final/2020-09-10-Non-AIR'
              'AC/html/eAIP/ENR-3.1-en-GB.html?s=B2EE1C5E1D2A684224A194E69D18338A560504FC#ENR-3.1')

df[0].to_csv('ENR3.0.csv')
```

Comment: hi there! thank you for the link, will read up on it. I have made the required adjustment to  `import pandas as pd`but it still did not convert all the HTML table over to CSV file.

Comment: That is because pandas alone will not solve your purpose, you will have to parse HTML file using lxml or HTML parser so that you can extract required info and store it in tabular format. BeautifulSoup or something similar will solve your purpose.

Comment: try this lib: pip install html-to-csv (https://pypi.org/project/html-to-csv/) . this might also be helpful. Reading: https://gist.github.com/AO8/63b9a5acb9fb238cbed13a0269d14137

Comment: ok, i will read up,thank you so much for the help :)