# Why is BeautifulSoup not returning child elements?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a url to download an xlsx file from this page, using Python 3 and BeautifulSoup 4: https://psnc.org.uk/funding-and-statistics/funding-distribution/retained-margin-category-m/

I need to get the url for most recent file, which is at index 0 in a list of `<p>` tags inside a `<div>`, and I can get it using JS in the console like this:

```
var link = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle_container")[2].children[1].children[0].href
```

If I use BS4 to get *all* of the `<p>` tags on the page, the link I want is in the list:

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cat_m_site = "https://psnc.org.uk/funding-and-statistics/funding-distribution/retained-margin-category-m/"

page = requests.get(cat_m_site)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
p_elements = soup.find_all('p')

        for item in p_elements:
            print(item)
```

If I try to reproduce the JS solution by getting the `<div>` that contains the links, There should be a list of 29 `<p>` elements but the list is empty:

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cat_m_site = "https://psnc.org.uk/funding-and-statistics/funding-distribution/retained-margin-category-m/"

page = requests.get(cat_m_site)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'toggle_container'})
children = divs[2].findChildren("p", recursive=True)

        for child in children:
            print(child)
```

I prefer this way because I 'know' the link will be in the 0'th element in this div, but I feel like I'm missing something about the findChildren method.

Comment: Does that page use javascript to dynamically create those elements?  If so, you can't use requests to get the page content; you'll need something that is javascript-aware, like Selenium.

Comment: This right url is : https://psnc.org.uk/funding-and-statistics/pharmacy-funding/margins-survey/ the one yout provided does not have a link to an xlsx file.

Comment: @cgte - sorry, parhaps my question wasn't clear enough.  The url I provided contains links to about 29 xlsx files within one of the `<div class="toggle_container">` elements.  The text of the link is **"Category M: products and prices"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')` instead

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cat_m_site = "https://psnc.org.uk/funding-and-statistics/funding-distribution/retained-margin-category-m/"

page = requests.get(cat_m_site)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'toggle_container'})
children = divs[2].findChildren("p", recursive=True)

for child in children:
    print(child)
```

**Output:**

```
<p><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Category-M-201920-Q3-Oct-Dec-with-Aug-19-combined.xlsx">Category M 2019/20 Q3 Oct-Dec (with Aug 19 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Category-M-2019-August-with-Jul-19-combined.xlsx">Category M 2019 August (with Jul 19 combined</a>) (MS Excel)</p>
<p><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Category-M-2019-20-Q2-Jul-Sep-with-Apr-19-combined.xlsx">Category M 2019/20 Q2 Jul-Sep (with Apr 19 combined) </a>(MS Excel)</p>
<p><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Cat-M-Apr-2019-1.xlsx">Category M: 2019/20 Q1 Apri-June (with Jan 2019 combined) </a>(MS Excel)</p>
<p><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Category-M-2018.19-Q4-JanMar-with-Nov-18-combined.xlsx">Category M: 2018/19 Q4 Jan-Mar (with Nov 18 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Category-M-Nov-18.xlsx">Category M: 2018 November (with Oct 18 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Category-M-2018.19-Q3-OctDec-with-Aug-18-combined.xlsx">Category M: 2018/19 Q3 Oct-Dec (with Aug 18 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p><a href="http://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Category-M-2018.19-Q2-JulSep-with-Apr-18-combined.xlsx">Category M: 2018/19 Q2 Jul-Sep (with Apr 18 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Category-M-2018.19-Q1-AprJun-with-Jan-18-combined-v2.xlsx">Category M: 2018/19 Q1 Apr-Jun (with Jan 18 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Category-M-Jan-18.xlsx">Category M: 2017/18 Q4 Jan-Mar (with Oct 17 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Category-M-Oct-17.xlsx">Category M: 2017/18 Q3 Oct-Dec (with Aug 17 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Category-M-Aug-17.xlsx">Category M: 2017 August (with Jul 17 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Category-M-Jul-17.xlsx">Category M: 2017/18 Q2 Jul-Sep (with Apr 17 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Category-M-Apr-17.xlsx">Category M: 2017/18 Q1 Apr-Jun (with Jan 17 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Category-M-Jan-17.xlsx">Category M: 2016/17 Q4 Jan-Mar (with Oct 16 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Category-M-Oct-16.xlsx">Category M: 2016/17 Q3 Oct-Dec (with Jul 16 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Category-M-Jul-16.xlsx">Category M: 2016/17 Q2 Jul – Sep (with Jun 16 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Category-M-June-16.xlsx">Category M: 2016 June (with Apr 16 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Category-M-April-16.xlsx" rel="">Category M: 2016/17 Q1 Apr – Jun (with Jan 16 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Category-M-2015.16-Q4-Jan-Mar-with-Oct-15-combined.xlsx">Category M: 2015/16 Q4 Jan – Mar (with Oct 15 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Category-M-2015.16-Q3-Oct-Dec-with-Jul-15-combined.xlsx">Category M: 2015/16 Q3 Oct </a><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Jun-15-and-Apr-15-Cat-M-prices.xlsx">–</a><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Category-M-2015.16-Q3-Oct-Dec-with-Jul-15-combined.xlsx"> Dec (with Jul 15 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Jun-15-and-Apr-15-Cat-M-prices.xlsx">Category M: 2015/16 Q2 Jul – Sep (with Apr 15 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Apr_15_and_Jan_15_Cat_M_prices-2.xlsx">Category M: 2015/16 Q1 Apr – Jun (with Jan 15 combined) updated</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Jan_15_and_Oct_14_Cat_M_prices.xlsx">Category M: 2014/15 Q4 Jan – Mar (with Oct 14 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Oct_14_and_Jul_14_Cat_M_prices.xlsx">Catgegory M: 2014/15 Q3 Oct – Dec (with Jul 14 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Jul_14_and_Apr_14_Cat_M_Prices.xlsx">Category M: 2014/15 Q2 Jul – Sep (with Apr 14 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="https://psnc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Apr_14_and-Jan_14_Cat_M_Prices.xls.xlsx">Category M: 2014/15 Q1 Apr – Jun (with Jan 14 combined)</a> (MS Excel)</p>
<p></p>
```

Comment: thanks very much.  Would you be able to add something to briefly explain why lxml worked but html.parser didn't?

Comment: @JeremyFox, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494505/python-difference-between-lxml-and-html-parser-and-html5lib-with-beautifu)